# RStudio w/Git Integrated throws index.lock error on commit

Tags: git, rstudio

This is is a weird one. It appears to be an issue with RStudio (currently running version 0.99.467 on Windows).

I'm trying to integrate the Git functionality with RStudio so that my team can collaborate on a couple of projects. All works well(ish) until the moment when I want to commit a change. I get the, dreaded error below:

> fatal: Unable to create 'v:/path/to/files/.git/index.lock': File
>   exists.
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
>   git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
>   process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

There is no index.lock file, and I can commit changes to the repository fine from the command line. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this so I can commit within the RStudio gui?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by **pressing the "refresh" button** in the "review changes" window. Since then I did not encounter the problem again so I could not reproduce this problem... but maybe it could help you too...

Comment: It might take multiple refreshes, but this works for me on a network drive.

Comment: I clicked the "refresh" button at the top, right-hand side of the Git pane, and that worked for me, [not sure if that's what Andy VY meant by the "review changes" window]

Answer (score 2):

**IF you´re running Linux in a VM** and you have you local rep lying in a shared folder, Windows seems to always lock the ".git/index" file. Placing the local repo in a folder which is not shared with my host OS solved the problem for me. Workaround for accessing files with host OS: use a cloud.

Comment: is there a solution to this? I have an ubuntu VM running RStudio, accessing the files on Windows host.  Unfortunately I cannot change my setup. Thanks